# Почему двум переменным присваивается одно введенное в консоль значение?

Tags: c#

Только осваиваю C#,и не могу понять почему введенное значение дублируется. Пробовал по разному. Если использовать Read(),то ввод второго значения просто игнорируется,и сразу выводится значение переменных(одинаковое). Если сначала использовать ReadLine(),а потом Read(),то консоль уже не пропускает второй ввод,но значения все равно одинаковые. Если и там,и там использовать ReadLine то получаю ошибку,что строка не может быть больше одной буквы. Как это исправить?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { int x=0, y=0;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите первую букву Вашего имени");
           char name = Convert.ToChar(value : Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Введите последнюю букву Вашей фамилии");

           char lastname = Convert.ToChar(value : Console.Read());
            x = Convert.ToInt32(name);
            y = Convert.ToInt32(lastname);
            Console.WriteLine("name={0,3},last={1,3}", name, lastname);
            Console.WriteLine("x={0,3},y={1,3}",x,y);
            Console.WriteLine("x-y={0,3}", x-y);
            if (x > y)
            {
                while (x >= y) 
                {
                    Console.Write("{0,1}   ", Convert.ToChar(x));
                    x--;
                }
            }
            else if (y >= x) 
            {
while (y>= x) 
            {    Console.Write("{0,1}  ", Convert.ToChar(y));
                y--;}
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое число внутри `{...}` - индекс параметра после строки формата.

```
Console.WriteLine("name={0,3},last={1,3}", name, lastname);
Console.WriteLine("x={0,3},y={1,3}", x, y);
```

Comment: @Alexey `Convert.ToChar(x)`

Comment: Я додумался и сделал чуть по другому,до того как Вы ответили,но почему-то выводится только первая буква...
P.S. В случае с Вашим способом все тоже самое

Comment: @Alexey К сожалению, мне сквозь монитор не видно, до чего Вы додумались.

Comment: Я код в вопросе изменил,забыл написать об этом

Comment: С проблемой разобрался,спасибо за помощь. Как можно закрыть вопрос?